# Shaftless Hall encoder

Tags: pcb-design, dc-motor, motor-controller, feedback, hall-effect

### Shaftless hall encoder

I am building a robot, and one of the stumbling-blocks I found was motor positional control.
It seems like the [Quadrature encoder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrature_encoder) is a good choice, but I have no rear axis on the Motors I am using.

Motor:
[Micro 6mm motor](https://nfpshop.com/product/6mm-mini-dc-gear-motor-15mm-type-model-nfp609-5-14-0675-standard-shaft)
[image: Motor]
[image: Diagram of motor]
I have tried to find a way to use hall effect sensors for encoding, but they seem to all require a magnetic disk on the back
[image: Wikipedia animation]
[image: Ebay encoder]

This motor does not have a shaft available for an encoder, and it would probably be too big to use on the robot platform. Is there any way to have the motor mounted parallel to the PCB, with a shaftless Hall encoder? [image: Mount position]

EDIT:
found magnets that can fit in wheel I am using
[image: Wheel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idler wheel with an encoder would be more accurate since it is not driven so does not slip.

Alternatively, with wheels that small the  ground needs to be flat and you are close enough to it to maybe use an optical mouse-type IC.

Comment: Great Idea! only the problem is that they are not that accurate.

Comment: Also, any suggestions on parts to use? 1.6mm height is O.K for this, as I could not seem to find any parts

Comment: Which method are you asking about? I don't have any experience with the optical mouse-type solutions. I just know it has been done and it's a lot of tinkering since there aren't any "ready-made" solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Secondary shaft is not a problem, as I have found 1x1x1 mm micro-magnets, I will be using these in the drive wheel to provide positional control.